# How to restore VS Code Sidebar settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code comes with a Source Control tab on the sidebar, I think I accidentally dragged the icon into the 'Explorer' tab icon, now all the source control boxes are dragged in here and the folder + files list which used to be the default in the Explorer tab is now pushed to the bottom.

How may I undo this change?

[image: vs_code_sidebar]

Comment: Run the command: `View: Reset View Locations`.

Comment: Thank you! Could you add this as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In general, if you have moved some view to a place, called a `ViewContainer`, like the Side Bar or Side Panel or Panel and you can't figure out how to get back to the default location for that view use the command

`View: Reset View Locations` to reset all the views to their default locations.

Comment: Is this stored as part of the *settings.json* or where can one find this?

Answer (score 2):

open the Command Palette with Ctrl+Shift+P, then run the command View: Reset View Locations